# jquery scrollTop event on mobile not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, scrolltop

I have a div that fade in if the scrollTop value is over 122px.

This works fine on a desktop (with the browser window shrunk to below 500px width to mimic mobile screen size) but it doesn't work on a mobile. Is there a work around?

My HTML:

```
<div id="topNav" class="fw">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="scrollLogo">
      <img src="images/dualLogoMob-scroll.png" width="63" height="30" alt=""/>
    </div><!-- /#scrollLogo-->
    <div class="twelve columns">
      <a href="#" onClick="return false;" id="mobMenuTrig" class="test">Menu</a>
    </div><!-- /.twelve.columns-->
  </div><!-- /.container-->
</div><!-- /#topNav-->
```

Working URL: http://www.altitude-digital.co.uk/dev/DUAL-SITE/index.php

My current JS:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#scrollLogo").hide();
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
          if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 122) {
            jQuery('#scrollLogo').fadeIn();
          } else {
            jQuery('#scrollLogo').fadeOut();
          }
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: `jQuery(function () {` this block is also document ready use one of them.

Comment: this should function fine: [https://jsfiddle.net/hnyaq2hk/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/hnyaq2hk/2/)

Answer (score 0):

**http://jsbin.com/voxace/**

Remove the `overflow: scroll` from `#sitewrap`

To spare your fingers from writing `"jQuery"` all over the place use:

```
<script>
jQuery(function( $ ){ // DOM ready and $ alias secured

   // Free to use $ as usual

   var $scrLogo = $('#scrollLogo'); // Cache your selectors for expensive DOM lookup
   var $win = $(window);

   $scrLogo.hide();
   $win.on("scroll load", function () { // Do on scroll but also on win load!
     if ($(this).scrollTop() > 122) {
       $scrLogo.stop().fadeIn(); // Use stop() to prevent anim. buildups
     } else {
       $scrLogo.stop().fadeOut();
     }
   });

 });
</script>
```

Comment: Ah, this was just a test i was working on but to no avail. I have removed this div and css

Comment: @jarrettowen open the demo on mobile. It has to work.